Effective way of combinig guitar and piano warm-ups?
As a guitar player I mostly use "spider-style" warmup exercices variations to train my 4 left hand fingers.
As an occasional keyboard player I use thirds progressions warm-up exercices on both hand to improve finger independance.
A tricky problem is that my left hand ring finger build different muscle memory from both exercices, that make the finger in a V shaped non-optimal position for guitar playing.
Does a ring finger specific exercice exist or should I do even more warm-ups if I want to play both instruments?

I play (30+years) and teach (17+ years) both instruments. I don’t think I’ve experienced what you’re describing. Sounds like you’re having a technical challenge on guitar and your theory is that the challenge is caused by your piano technique? Can you give us a bit more detail? If I’m understanding correctly, my first thought is that something is wrong with your technique on one or both instruments.

As @ToddWilcox wrote, some more information is needed, such as 1) what exactly you're playing on the piano and what fingering you're using for it, and 2) What do you mean by a "V" shape regarding your left-hand ring finger. If possible, pictures of your hand(s) on piano and guitar would be very helpful.

Don't over-think this.  Your hands are multi-purpose tools - perhaps the ultimate multi-purpose tools!   Positioning them in one way to do one job won't stop you positioning them in another way to do something else.
But, other than the transferable benefit of simply keeping your fingers moving, I think each instrument does demand its own practice routine.

Since the actions of fingers are rather different from piano to guitar, it's just as wise to use separate warm up exercises for each. After all, when you swap from one to the other, whatever you've done to limber up on one won't help the other. Hence the question, I guess.
Unless you're about to play really challenging stuff on either instrument, warm ups could be quite short, if at all. Instead, I tend to play stuff that's within my capability before performing on each instrument (played both for 65 yrs, taught both for 55, if that's a criterion). In lessons, due to their short duration, I just get students to play whatever for a couple of minutes. Seems to work!
That apart, unless you're swapping piano to guitar to piano in quick succession, warm up on one whatever you do will help a little with the other, as exercises for one are, as previous, different from the other.
A difficult question to answer (no others forthcoming) but from my experience, that's it.
